# how to convert query this query to laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
SELECT *
FROM `digital_useraccess`
left join digital_publisher ON
access_publisher = pub_auto
left join digital_issue ON
issue_publisher = pub_auto
WHERE 1
```

without using laravel DB class method

Comment: Why you doesnt want to use DB ?

Comment: I want to join tables through Model as I predefined model in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as reference

```
    ModelName::where(conditions)
    ->leftjoin('digital_publisher','access_publisher','pub_auto')
    ->leftjoin('digital_issue','issue_publisher ','pub_auto')
    ->select('column_1','column_2',...)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

```
  ::query()->where('<cplumn>' , '<operator>' ,
 '<value>')->leftJoin('digital_publisher', 'access_publisher',
 '=','pub_auto')->leftJoin('digital_issue', 'issue_publisher', '=',
 'pub_auto')->select('<columns>')->get();/find();/first();
```